# How do I export schema after upgrading Hibernate to 5.1.0?

Tags: java, hibernate

I've recently updated Hibernate from 5.0 to 5.1 and the `SchemaExport` API has changed. The migration docs mention this change, but do not explain how to use the newer API. Moreover, I have not been able to find any other supporting sample to fix the breaking change.

Comment: You may compare the code for both tags, here is 5.1, just select the tag you want and see what did change : https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.1.0/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.java

Comment: IMO I'd share the relevant code you have and then make the question about what needs to be changed to make it Hibernate 5.1 API compatible. That would maximize the usefulness to other people who may run into the same problem. And this is the very unhelpful 'migration guide' referred to: http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/5.1/migration/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled upon this code diff that helped me solve the differences in the API: https://gitlab.nuiton.org/nuiton/topia/commit/0c57f073ad879a981e9fa3315f0e04669a57858b

Here's my code which exports schema for any Class marked with @Entity annotation to the output window.

```
  static void getDDL(String packageName, String propertiesFile) throws IOException {

    MetadataSources metadata = new MetadataSources(
        new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .loadProperties(propertiesFile)
            .build());

    new Reflections(packageName)
        .getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class)
        .forEach(metadata::addAnnotatedClass);

    //STDOUT will export to output window, but other `TargetType` values are available to export to file or to the db.
    EnumSet<TargetType> targetTypes = EnumSet.of(TargetType.STDOUT);

    SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport();

    export.setDelimiter(";");
    export.setFormat(true);

    export.createOnly(targetTypes, metadata.buildMetadata());
}
```

Comment: What is Reflections? Does not compile.

Comment: @powder366 that's from package `org.reflections`

Answer (score 0):

[leojh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/782096/leojh) answer works and created the script. But hangs and never stop executing? Seems it first exports and then import. Only want export... and why is Java not exiting?

Output:

```
INFO Dialect:Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
INFO SchemaExport:Running hbm2ddl schema export 
INFO SchemaCreatorImpl:Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@1bd39d‌​3c'
```

Class:

```
    String file="export.sql";

    try {
        MetadataSources metadata = new MetadataSources(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .loadProperties(new File(DatabaseCreator.class.getClassLoader().getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml").getFile()))
                .build());

        new Reflections("ch.abc.mapping").getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class).forEach(metadata::addAnnotatedClass);

        EnumSet<TargetType> targetTypes = EnumSet.of(TargetType.SCRIPT);

        new File(file).delete();

        SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport();
        export.setDelimiter(";");
        export.setFormat(true);
        export.setOutputFile(file);
        export.execute(targetTypes, SchemaExport.Action.CREATE, metadata.buildMetadata());
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure. That could be because a myriad things. For me, I run it in a Console Application and it exists fine.

Comment: Funny. Either way for me it hangs on import as showed above. Generate the file correctly though. Im running from within IntelliJ.

Comment: See which line it's hanging on and see why. Maybe you're not disposing of a resource or connection.

Comment: I finally added  System.exit(0); See correction above. Thanks for your help with your code!

Comment: Closing the ServiceRegistry fixed it for me.