# how to export schema in hibernate 5.1.0

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

I am trying to migrate hibernate from `5.0.3` to `5.1.0`. I tried the example that was given on the link below but it did not worked for me.

[How do I export schema after upgrading Hibernate to 5.1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993598/how-do-i-export-schema-after-upgrading-hibernate-to-5-1-0)

My code for exporting schema in hibernate `5.0.3`:

```
    MetadataImplementor metadataImpl = (MetadataImplementor) metadata;
    SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(metadataImpl, connection);
    schemaExport.execute(Target.EXPORT, SchemaExport.Type.CREATE);
```

Now how do i use this schema export in hibernate `5.1.0`