# Hibernate migration for SchemaUpdate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I've run into a really weird case.

I've used for a long time `hibernate-core` version `5.0.11.final`, one of the things I've done in my code is to manually create the database with new schema and tables:

```
@Service
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CreateSchemaService implements InitializingBean {
    @Autowired
    private DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(getProperties())
                .build();

        MetadataImplementor metadata = (MetadataImplementor) new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Pishoto.class)
                .buildMetadata();

        // Hibernate 5.3.9 Migration
        // EnumSet<TargetType> targetTypes = EnumSet.of(TargetType.DATABASE, TargetType.STDOUT);
        // new SchemaUpdate().execute(targetTypes, metadata, serviceRegistry);

        // Hibernate 5.0.11
        new SchemaUpdate(serviceRegistry, metadata).execute(true, true);
    }

    private Map<String, String> getProperties() {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

        properties.put(Environment.URL, dataSourceProperties.getUrl());
        properties.put(Environment.USER, dataSourceProperties.getUsername());
        properties.put(Environment.PASS, dataSourceProperties.getPassword());
        properties.put(Environment.DEFAULT_SCHEMA, "hibernate_poc");
        properties.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "none");
        properties.put(Environment.NON_CONTEXTUAL_LOB_CREATION, "true");
        properties.put(Environment.DRIVER, dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName());

        return properties;
    }
}
```

While upgrading to version `5.3.9` I had to change some code (since version `5.1.0.final` the [`Schema Migration` api was changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35995356/1706545)), so I used the new API (in comment in the previous section):

```
EnumSet<TargetType> targetTypes = EnumSet.of(TargetType.DATABASE, TargetType.STDOUT);
new SchemaUpdate().execute(targetTypes, metadata, serviceRegistry);
```

But this doesn't create my schema automatically anymore, only if the schema is manually created then it will create my tables.

I'm using a `Postgres` db, and I checked that the db user role have all the right permissions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there are **errors** performing schemas updates.
To see them, enable the special flag:

```
SchemaUpdate update = new SchemaUpdate();
update.setHaltOnError(true);
```